# Proper way to update mongo in patch action in web api

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, http-patch

I want to implement Patch action in web api,
consider I have Customer collection in mongo like this:

```
public string Id{ get; set; }
public string Name{ get; set; }
public string Family{ get; set; }
public string Sex{ get; set; }
public string City{ get; set; }
public string CustomerId{ get; set; }
```

in my api i receive this object as input. client can edit one or many of these fields,if property is null it means the value should be remained previous value.
what I want to do is in mongo query I wan to say if property is null dont update consider this:

```
var filter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(s => s.CustomerId, CustomerId);
var builder = Builders<Customer>.Update.Set(???)//set only not null values
mongo.UpdateOne(filter, builder);
```

*By the way any better solution for this is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like this.

```
var filter = Builders<Customer>.Filter
    .Eq(s => s.CustomerId, customer.CustomerId); //perhaps requires an index on CustomerId field
var update = Builders<Customer>.Update
    .Set(p => p.CustomerId, customer.CustomerId);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customer.City))
    update = update.Set(p => p.City, customer.City);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customer.Name))
    update = update.Set(p => p.Name, customer.Name);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customer.Family))
    update = update.Set(p => p.Family, customer.Family);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customer.Sex))
    update = update.Set(p => p.Sex, customer.Sex);

customers.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

A different approach might consider your customer entity as a whole (document oriented databases encourage this approach), thus always updating the entity altogether and avoiding fine-grained updates (that are more likely in case of R-DBMSs). In this case, you might write something like this.

```
var customerFromDb = customers
    .Find(p => p.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId)
    .Single();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customer.City))
    customerFromDb.City = customer.City;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customer.Name))
    customerFromDb.Name = customer.Name;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customer.Family))
    customerFromDb.Family = customer.Family;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customer.Sex))
    customerFromDb.Sex = customer.Sex;

customers.ReplaceOne(p => p.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId, customerFromDb);
```

This second approach has the following Pro and Cons.

## Pro

- the update happens *in the domain-layer* (possibly through well suited methods), thus allowing enforcement of all domain rules and preventing dirty data to go into the database; thus it is more *object-oriented*.

## Cons

- this approach requires two hits on the database (one for the read and one for the update);
- in case your entity is large, network has to transport more data than strictly needed.

Considering that *premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming* ([here](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)), in general I would go for the second approach, falling back to the first one only in case of very strict performance requirements or low network bandwidth.

Comment: what is the reason behind this code:var update = Builders<Customer>.Update
    .Set(p => p.CustomerId, customer.CustomerId); because we dont want to update this, is there any better way for solution one to avoid this update?

Comment: It grants that `update` variable holds a defined  `UpdateDefinition<Customer>` to be passed to `UpdateOne()` method, even if no updates are requested (i.e. in case all received properties are null). Alternatively, you might test the need for triggering the update. But this would request a full inspection of the data structure (quite unmaintainable) and would be possibly a premature optimization.